# How to change the default number of lines in ArgoCD UI

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

Currently we are using ArgoCD to deploy our microservices.
The dev team wants to be able to see more than 100 lines of logs when they enter to the pod logs in the UI.

I have tried to update to version 2.6.7 since I see the issue has been solved here https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/6199 but I still see the same 100 lines as default. Anyone knows if I have to update something else in the configmaps for argocd-server?

Comment: This seems to be part of 2.7 milestone. You can try 2.7-RC or wait for 2.7 to be released.

Comment: Just upgraded to 2.7.2 and I can see now up to 10000 lines per page. Thanks!